# HTML5.js for IE7/8 support

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have read a lot about adding HTML5.js for IE7/8 support. Even though the documentation says that adding html5.js just causes IE7/8 to not ignore HTML5 tags and apply the styles.
I am really confused as to what it does, like does it have any impact on CSS3 styles working on IE OR it just causes CSS to be applied to HTML5 elements. 
Could i please get to to see an easy example with/without HTML5.js on IE.

Comment: There is no such thing as "html5.js". Are you referring to the [HTML5 enabling script?](http://remysharp.com/2009/01/07/html5-enabling-script/)

Comment: actually html5.js was born here http://remysharp.com/2009/01/07/html5-enabling-script/ and resides here http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/  do some research before you comment. i agree why the negative vote? there are so many trolls here.

Comment: @albert The file is called "html5.js", but the project is called html5-shiv. I know what that is, the blog post I (and you) linked to is the first result in a Google search for "html5.js", but that does not necessarily mean the OP is referring to that. The question was downvoted probably because it is difficult to understand, and it is not following best practices by asking multiple questions in one question

Comment: @albert In addition, if you're referring to my comment, I did not downvote the question. It should be obvious given the OP's comment was dated more than a week before mine. Your definition of "troll" is strange; trolls are people who deliberately leave inflammatory comments to elicit responses. Downvoting poor posts is never "trolling"

Comment: it is called html5.js in the file name. sorry that is so confusing. i didn't say that you specifically downvoted the question. i've seen this behavior all over this site and it's weak. this is a legit question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html5.js works by creating polyfills via JavaScript that specifically enforce certain rules of html5 elements in browsers that do not support them. but even after the js turns them "on", you are still going to have to target them via css to enforce styles. check out this fiddle in any browser that doesn't support html5, then uncomment out the script element and view it again. you'll see what i'm talking about http://jsfiddle.net/TR8z5/

Comment: Your use of the term "polyfill" is incorrect. Polyfills are scripts that implement newer features in unspported browsers - for instance, a `<progress>` polyfill will allow me to use `<progress>` in older browsers that do not support them without having to add additional markup. The project page for HTML5 shiv does not refer to it as a 'polyfill'

Comment: your just fishing dude. by your definition, html5.js is a polyfill, it implements new features in ie that ie doesn't support.

Answer (score 0):

<s>If I recall correctly, without html5.js, older web browsers will just ignore tags it doesn't recognize, essentially showing nothing.  With html5.js, older browsers will recognize html5 tags and will therefore be able to render and apply CSS.</s>

Nope, [I guess not](http://benmccallum.wordpress.com/2011/05/23/making-older-browsers-recognize-and-correctly-style-the-new-html5-semantic-tags/).

CSS3 will not work on older browsers, no matter what you do.

Comment: This is incorrect. Older browsers, such as Firefox 3.6, will display these elements as inline elements by default. Older versions of IE will also not allow them to be styled, unless the enabling script is used. None of these browsers will "not show" these elements.